# Hiding/showing multiple items when I click a button

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick, hidden

I have 3 buttons, with ID's `'btn1' 'btn2' 'btn3'`, and I want each of them to hide a number of elements: each element has the ID `'sect1' 'sect2' ... 'sect3'` and belongs to the class `'hidden'`. For some reason my code does not work. The first button is completely messed up, and the 2nd and 3rd one only display one of the elements assigned to them. My code is this:

````
var divs
var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");
var btn3 = document.getElementById("btn3");

btn1.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect1",this);

toggleDivs("sect2",this);

toggleDivs("sect3",this);

toggleDivs("sect4",this);
};

btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect5",this);
};
btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect6",this);
};
btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect7",this);
};
btn2.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect8",this);
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect9",this);
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect10",this);
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect11",this);
};
btn3.onclick = function(event){
event.preventDefault();
toggleDivs("sect12",this);
};

function toggleDivs(s,btn){

if(btn.classList.contains("btn_active_state")){
document.getElementById(s).classList.remove("shown");
btn.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
document.getElementById(s).classList.remove("shown");
return;
}else{
btn1.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn2.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn3.classList.remove("btn_active_state");
btn.classList.add("btn_active_state");
document.getElementById("sect1").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect2").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect3").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect4").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect5").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect6").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect7").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect8").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect9").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect10").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect11").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById("sect12").classList.remove("shown");
document.getElementById(s).classList.add("shown","fade");
}

}

//force button1 state initialise, if required
btn1.focus();
btn1.click();
</script>
<style>

.elementor-editor-active .hidden{
display:block;
}
.hidden{
display:none;
}
.shown{
display: block !important;
animation: fade_in_anim 0.5s;
}
.btn_active_state{
background-color: #FFCC00 !important;
}

@keyframes fade_in_anim {
0% {
opacity: 0;
transform: translateY(-30px);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
transform: translateY(0px);
}
}

</style>```
````

Comment: your first button is messed up because each time you call toggleDivs(), you remove the show class from the previous sect.
and the other buttons only display one element because the onclick property can only refer to one function.

Comment: problem is with the toggledivs() function because it only adds class to one sect and removes from all others, while you have assigned many sects to one button

Answer (score 1):

You can map buttons and sections :

```js
const buttons = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^='btn']")]
const mapping = [[0, 4], [4, 8], [8,12]]
const sections = [...document.querySelectorAll("[id^='sect']")]

for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleDivs(this)
    for(let j = mapping[i][0]; j < mapping[i][1]; j++) {
      sections[j].classList.add("shown", "fade")
    }
  })
}

function toggleDivs(btn){
  buttons.forEach(b => b.classList.remove("btn_active_state"))
  btn.classList.add("btn_active_state")
  sections.forEach(s => s.classList.remove('shown'))
}

//force button1 state initialise, if required
btn1.focus();
btn1.click();
```

```css
.shown{
  display: block !important;
  animation: fade_in_anim 0.5s;
}
.btn_active_state{
  background-color: #FFCC00 !important;
}
@keyframes fade_in_anim {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-30px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
[id^='sect'] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
<button id="btn3">btn3</button>
<div id="sect1">sect1</div>
<div id="sect2">sect2</div>
<div id="sect3">sect3</div>
<div id="sect4">sect4</div>
<div id="sect5">sect5</div>
<div id="sect6">sect6</div>
<div id="sect7">sect7</div>
<div id="sect8">sect8</div>
<div id="sect9">sect9</div>
<div id="sect10">sect10</div>
<div id="sect11">sect11</div>
<div id="sect12">sect12</div>
```

Comment: I implemented this and it works! But after I saved the changes and refreshed, the page, the code doesn't work anymore... Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Hey mate, this solution works with this html markup, do you have different ids or btns?

Comment: I do not. The solution works on my website as well while I'm in editing mode, but not on the actual website.

Comment: Sorry mate, i can't help you unless i debug your live site :( You can check if JS works on your live site, put some alert, console.log and try to debug